# How to tell the version number of RxJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, rxjs5

How to tell the version of the installed RxJS from the code? For example:

```
var Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');
console.log(Rx.rev);   // undefined
console.log(Rx.version);  // undefined
```

Second question: How to tell if it's rxjs5 ?

Comment: Don't check the version, check if the classes and methods you want exist (like a polyfill might do). It's far more flexible.

Comment: Thanks. I think RxJS may not have backward compatibility (not sure). You are right, but I didn't want to use it in the production code. Just want to report in which version my example is tested.

Comment: Nothing wrong with logging some version info, always good to have when debugging. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
const package = require('rxjs/package.json');
const is5 = /^5\./.test(package.version);

console.log(package.version);
console.log(is5);
```

Comment: Thanks. What is `/^5\./`  ?

Comment: I think he means in the browser

Answer (score 28):

This will show all NPM package versions if you installed with NPM.

```
npm list --depth=0
```

If you leave out the --depth then you'll get all their dependencies also.

Comment: Thank you. This is very useful.

Answer (score 17):

You can install the 'version-check' library from npm using

```
npm install -g version-check
```

And then call

```
version-check rxjs
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try and check on the list

`ng --version`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).